# Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that if $18|n^3$, then $18|n^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that if $18|n^3$, then $18|n^2$.

I realize that this does not also apply to $18|n$, since it works for $n=6$. I think that in order to solve this, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $18$ divides $n^3$. This means that there is some integer $k$ such that $18k=n^3$. Notice that $18=2\cdot 3^2$. So $2$ divides $n^3$ and $3^2$ divides $n^3$.

If $2$ divides $n^3$, what can you say about $n$ itself?

If $3$ divides $n^3$, again what can be said about $n$?

Consider prime factorizations.

I hope this helps!

Comment: How do we know that both 2 and $3^2$ divide $n^3$

Comment: $n^3=18k = 2(9k)$ so $2$ divides $n^3$. Similarly for $3$. :)

Comment: Thank makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the prime factorization. If $p\mid n^2$, then $p\mid n$. In this case, you have $n^3$...